# Adding a Reference to a Project in Visual Studio which includes Resources

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have a C# Application with a number of classes that I have written nUnit [TestFixture] classes.  This application also includes a \Resources*.bmp directory in the project.

I have included these [TestFixture] classes in a separate "Class Library" project.

I added a reference in my "Class Library" project that points to my C# application project so I can write test code that includes classes I have defined in my application.

When I build my "Class Library" project I get the following error:

> "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Microsoft.Common.targets(1211,9): error MSB3114: Could not find file 'Resources\loschart.bmp reference by assembly C:\\.exe.manifext"

How do I tell my "Class Library" project about these Resources in my Application Project?

Comment: A solution i have found that seems to work is copying my Resources to my ..\bin\Debug\ so that the manifest file generated can find the resources.  I am guessing there is a setting somewhere where i can tell the binary about the \Resources\ directory without having to copy it to my debug and release, any ideas, or should i just add a custom post build event that moves the \Resources\ dir to my debug and realease folders?

Comment: If you add the files to your solution and then right click it and select "properties", you can choose what shall happen to it at build time. You probably want it to "copy local".  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1zz5y8c(v=vs.80).aspx